# Findall/3 for a sublist meeting certain criteria

Tags: list, prolog

I have two lists `L1` and `L2`:

```
L1=[1,4,5,6,7,8].
L2=[2,3].
```

And a predicate:

```
related(X,Y).
```

I want to find a list `L3`:

1. which is a sublist of `L1`
2. in which all the elements of `L3` are solutions for `Y`, where any of the values of `L2` being solutions for `X`

In other words, feed all the values of `L2` into `X`, and find out which of the values of `L1` will be corresponding solutions for `Y`.

Comment: Your title says what to use (`findall/3`) just describe your condition in the second argument. You want to find all the `X` such that, for example, `member(X, L1)` (your first condition), then you have a conjunctive condition, (b), to include. You can have a compound expression in `findall/3`: `findall(X, (member(X, L1), ..., ...), L3).`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `findall/3` this can be done this way (if I understand your conditions correctly):

```
findall(Y, (member(Y, L1), member(X, L2), related(X, Y)), L3).
```

In my comment, I had the `X` mixed around a bit due to misreading your conditions, but the idea is still the same. You just need to establish the proper goal as the second argument to `findall/3` to get the desired result.

---

If you want unique, ordered results, you can use `setof/3`:

```
setof(Y, (member(Y, L1), member(X, L2), related(X, Y)), L3).
```

Comment: Only problem I can think of is that one should use `once` for the `member(X, L2), related(X, Y)` since there should exist only one. Nice answer btw. +1.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks!, and, yes, good catch. I would probably use `setof/3` in that case. With `once/1` one would need to be careful not to prune out valid, unique solutions. It's not clear what the behavior of `related/2` is.

Comment: Set of is still not fully equivalent I think. The result should be a sublist. The original list can contain duplicates, which should perhaps be duplicated in the result. Nevertheless the question is a bit underspecified.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem agreed on the underspecification. I'm making unwritten assumptions with the `setof/3` option.

Comment: That's true, but in this case we do not do anything with `X`. We can only guess what the OP really wants and I think the two answers can co-exist ;).

Answer (score 1):

[`findall/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/3) is structured as:

```
findall(+Template, :Goal, -Bag)
```

where:

- `Bag` is the list of results you want to obtain;
- `Goal` is the predicate (or combination of predicates) that should succeed; and
- `Template` is an expression that describes the format of the results.

Now let's use this predicate to do something constructing:

> 1. which is a sublist of `L1`

You are looking *for all* elements `Y` in `L1`, so the template is clearly `X1` and the goal will at least contain `member(X,L1)`. So now or `findall/3` is shaped as:

```
findall(Y,(member(Y,L1),...),L3)
```

> 2. in which all the elements of `L3` are solutions for `Y`, where any of the values of `L2` being solutions for `X`

Since there should be at least one `X` in `L2` such that `related(X,Y)` holds. It means we use a `once/1` to enforce that from the moment one `X` is found, our call terminates (and no repetitions of `Y` occur) such that `X` is an element (`member/2`) of `L2` and `related/2` holds. `...` is thus equal to:

```
once((member(X,L2),rel(X,Y)))
```

Or now the full version:

```
findall(Y,(member(Y,L1),once((member(X,L2),rel(X,Y)))),L3)
```

**Example:**

Given for instance:

```
rel(2,1).
rel(3,1).
rel(2,4).
rel(3,7).
```

The result is:

```
?- L1=[1,4,5,6,7,8],L2=[2,3],findall(Y,(member(Y,L1),once((member(X,L2),rel(X,Y)))),L3).
L1 = [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
L2 = [2, 3],
L3 = [1, 4, 7].
```

So `1` will occur only once whereas there are two `X`s for `Y=1` for which the condition holds.